# Difference between SRC_URI and FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend in bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Why do we need to give path of files in `SRC_URI` even though we are including the files path in `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend` variable? For example:

```
SUMMARY = "Simple Hello application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI = "file://Hello_1.c \
           file://Hello_2.c \
              "

do_compile() {
         oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 Hello ${D}${bindir}
}
```

In the "files" folder I have two files: `hello1.c` and `hello2.c`. When I remove `SRC_URI` it outputs the following error,

```
ERROR: Hello-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
```

But if I remove
`FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend` it is working fine.

What is the purpose of the variable `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend`?

Why error occurs when I remove `SRC_URI` even though I'm including my files path in `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend`?

Comment: Kindly refer Yocto Manual for more detailed information: [Link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILESEXTRAPATHS)

Answer (score 10):

Simple way let assume  `meta-layer/recipes-core/example`

1. In above path created `hello` and `hello.bb`
2. Here `hello` is a directory having your source and other data  and `hello.bb is recipe`.

Now

**SRC_URI** : The `SRC_URI` variable always checks the data in `hello dir`  only.
**FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"** : if you add this line in your recipe, then the `SRC_URI` variable checks the data in `present directory`  where the `hello.bb` file present.

**In your case**

> FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/`files`:"

The `SRC_URI` variable checks the data in `files` dir where the `hello.bb` is present.

`Note`: Most of the time people will use this FILESEXTRAPATHS variable in `.bbappend` files to apply patches and other files to the recipe.

> For every `.bb` file, the `SRC_URI` variable is used to specify which files to fetch the source from - either from
> an online repository or a local one, and the `FILESEXTRAPATHS` specifies where these files are looked for, and depends on your source
> path.

Answer (score 8):

> BitBake uses the `SRC_URI` variable to point to source files
>   regardless of their location. Each recipe **must** have a `SRC_URI`
>   variable that points to the source.
>
> `SRC_URI = file://` Fetches files, which are usually files shipped
>   with the Metadata, from the local machine. The path is relative to the
>   FILESPATH variable. Thus, the build system searches, in order, from
>   the following directories, which are assumed to be a subdirectories of
>   the directory in which the recipe file (.bb) or append file
>   (.bbappend) resides:
>
> `FILESPATH`: The default set of directories the OpenEmbedded build
>   system uses when searching for patches and files. During the build
>   process, BitBake searches each directory in FILESPATH in the specified
>   order when looking for files and patches specified by each file:// URI
>   in a recipe.
>
> The default value for the FILESPATH variable is defined in the
>   base.bbclass class found in meta/classes in the Source Directory:
>
> ```
>  FILESPATH = "${@base_set_filespath(["${FILE_DIRNAME}/${BP}", \
>     "${FILE_DIRNAME}/${BPN}", "${FILE_DIRNAME}/files"], d)}"
> ```
>
> Do not hand-edit the `FILESPATH` variable;                     The
>   default directories BitBake uses when it processes recipes are
>   initially defined by the FILESPATH variable. You can extend FILESPATH
>   variable by using FILESEXTRAPATHS.
>
> **> Best practices dictate that you accomplish this by using
>   FILESEXTRAPATHS from within a .bbappend file**
>
> `FILESEXTRAPATHS`: **Extends** the search path the OpenEmbedded build system
>   uses when looking for files and patches as it processes recipes and
>   append files. The default directories BitBake uses when it processes
>   recipes are initially defined by the FILESPATH variable.
>
> If you want the build system to pick up files specified through a
>   SRC_URI statement from your append file, you need to be sure to extend
>   the FILESPATH variable by also using the FILESEXTRAPATHS variable from
>   within your append file.

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-FILESPATH

Back to your error, since each recipe MUST have a SRC_URI; it will not work if you delete it;

Since your recipe is not an `.bbappend`, adding `FILESEXTRAPATHS` is not appropriate and not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

### The quick answer is:

- SRC_URI doesn't let you specify a directory. It will always default to the "files" directory under the recipe.
- FILESEXTRAPATHS lets you specify a directory for the file.

### What this really means?

Even if you use SRC_URI in a `.bbappends`, SRC_URI will *only* point to the "files" directory of the `.bb`. It will never point to the "files" directory of the recipe appends. For recipe appends you must use FILESEXTRAPATHS to specify the non-default directory.